# Unicodedecodeerror with runserver and django

Tags: python, django

After setup all that django requires, and try python manage.py runserver command, I caught error. How to fix it? Or at least how take a look on what caused error?
Windows 7

```
python manage.py runserver
Validating models...

0 errors found
April 24, 2014 - 11:13:33
Django version 1.6.3, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x02C46CB0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aleksander\.virtualenvs\engineer\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", li
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Aleksander\.virtualenvs\engineer\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands
139, in inner_run
    self.stderr.write("Error: %s" % error_text)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: IMHO you're on python 2.x. Put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your files. This will force UTF8 string processing. See [the unicode page](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#python-2-x-s-unicode-support) for more details.

Comment: Please edit the question and put the contents of your `settings.py` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems, that windows gives some custom error, which uses non-ascii characters. To see the error, you could replace the `%s` to `%r` in C:\Users\Aleksander.virtualenvs\engineer\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands.py line 139.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` as first import of your files, to set compatibility between Python 2.X and 3.X about unicode formating.

Also, prefer using `'{}'.format(object)` to print an object or a variable, because format() handles character encoding.